# PHP Client browser download

Tags: php

I gave exact file path for PDF,  PDF also downloading without any interrupt. but when remove the exit after the  " exit ". PDF does not download not happening. i am doing some process after exit function.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$pdf_filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
readfile($file);
session_regenerate_id();
exit;
```

Comment: you can't regenerate the id like that. It works by re-setting the session ID cookie, and you can't issue a new cookie header AFTER you've performed output, which is what readfile() is doing.

Comment: actually i want to add this download in the mid of the flow. after download i will unlink tmp files and some sql update process.  so how to achieve my goal here.

Comment: doesn't matter. sess_regen_id uses header() to send the new ID to the user, and this WILL NOT WORK after you've performed output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that below code will work for you but first remove exit then flush the output at end and on top add ignore user abort and continue processing after flushing.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
//your code of force download using php readfile
ob_end_flush();
flush();
//code after flushing the output
```